# Need help adding custom CSS to eeh-navigation-sidebar

Tags: css

Just wondering if anyone has worked with eeh-navigation-sidebar and could offer some advice/help in applying custom CSS to specified elements.

I am trying to target the elements in the example below:
[image]

I want to be able to apply CSS to the items shown above, whilst also showing visually a custom hover styling as I move over each item.

Whilst the documentation on the [eeh-navigation](http://www.ethanhann.com/eeh-navigation/#/) webiste is good, it doesn't provide any extensive details on custom styling.  The only information I could find that was remotely relevant was [this page](https://github.com/ethanhann/eeh-navigation/issues/46) which details that child elements can be targeted by using the following code:

```
.eeh-navigation-sidebar li:not(.leaf).active {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}

.eeh-navigation-sidebar li.leaf.active {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: green !important;
}
```

Which seems to have no effect for me.
I have applied basic styling under the `.eeh-navigation-sidebar` class but my CSS skills are limited at the moment in order to workout how to drill down to more in-depth elements.